# Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i ( i b_{i} -(i-1) b_{i-1}) \in O(\log n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, approximation, time-series

Define 
$$
V(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i (i \times b_{i} - (i-1) \times b_{i-1}) 
$$
given that

- $a_i \leq A$, where $A$ is a constant.
- $b_i \leq i$
- $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = n $
- $b_0 = 0$

Is it true that $V(n) \in O(\log n)$?  How about $V(n) \in O(n)$?

Side note: $O(.)$ is the [big-Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), meaning that we don't care about constants; what matters is the growth in terms of the target variable $n$.

Comment: Setting aside my answer... are you certain your conditions are indeed what you meant to write? Because the only sequence $(b_i)_i$ satisfying your conditions is $b_i=i$. If there is any index $i^\ast$ such that $b_{i^\ast} < i^\ast$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{i} \leq \sum_{i\neq i^\ast} \frac{i}{i} + \frac{b_{i^\ast}}{i^\ast} = (n-1)+\frac{b_{i^\ast}}{i^\ast} < n$$ since you enforce $b_i \leq i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

Comment: Also, after your edits your title no longer matches your question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Thanks for catching the problem. I fixed it. Apologies.

Comment: See my edited answer. Oh darn, you changed the indices in your question again while I was typing. Will need to change it again.

Comment: Fixed my answer accordingly. Please, do not change the question again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume here all $a_i,b_i$ are non-negative.*

Unfortunately, $V(n) = O(\log n)$ is *not* true in general, and neither is $O(n)$. As a counterexample, assume for convenience $n=2m$ is even,and take
$$
a_{2i-1} = 0,\qquad a_{2i} = A
$$
and
$$
b_{2i-1} = 0,\qquad b_{2i} = 2
$$
for all $1\leq i \leq m$. This leads to $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = \sum_{i=1}^m b_{2i} = 2m = n$, and indeed $b_i \leq i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ as desired. But now, by construction only the terms with even indices remain in the sum defining $V(n)$ (since $a_{i}=0$ for odd $i$'s), and

$$
V(n) = A\sum_{i=1}^{m} (2i\underbrace{b_{2i}}_{=2}-\underbrace{(2i-1)b_{2i-1}}_{=0}) =  A\sum_{i=1}^{m} 4i = 4A\frac{m(m+1)}{2} = \Theta(m^2)= \Theta(n^2).
$$

Comment: Note that proving that we always have $V(n)=O(n^2)$ is rather easy, since $$V(n) \leq A\sum_{i=1}^n (ib_i+(i-1)b_{i-1})\leq 2A \sum_{i=1}^n ib_i \leq 2An \sum_{i=1}^n b_i = 2An^2.$$